# $\log(z_1z_2)=\log(z_1)+\log(z_2)$ where $z_1,z_2\in \mathbb{C}$\{0}

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I need to prove the set identity of the complex logarithm  $\log(z_1z_2)=\log(z_1)+\log(z_2)$ where $z_1,z_2\in \mathbb{C}$.

$\log(z_1)+\log(z_2)=${$\log|z_1|+\log|z_2|+i(\text{Arg}(z_1)+\text{Arg}(z_2)+4k\pi i|k\in \mathbb{Z}$}$\implies$

{$\log|z_1z_2|+i((\text{Arg}(z_1)+2k\pi i)+(\text{Arg}(z_2)+2k\pi i)|k\in \mathbb{Z}$}$\implies$

{$\log|z_1z_2|+i(\text{arg}(z_1)+\text{arg}(z_2))|k\in \mathbb{Z}$}$\implies$

{$\log|z_1z_2|+i(\text{Arg}(z_1z_2)+2k\pi i)|k\in \mathbb{Z}$}$\implies$$\log(z_1z_2)$

This is wclearly wrong I guess but this is how I tried to approach it. Would aprreciate any answers.Thanks a lot

Comment: this identity is simply not true for all complex values $z_1,z_2$ (and especially when one of them is $0$ ...)

Comment: @mercio Sorry about that edited the title thanks

Answer (score 1):

Right away your first line is not correct, because $$\log z_1 + \log z_2 = \log |z_1| + \log |z_2| + i(\operatorname{Arg} z_1 + \operatorname{Arg} z_2) + 2\pi i k_1 + 2 \pi i k_2,$$ where $k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb Z$; that is, the branch of the two logs do not necessarily come from the same value of $k$.

Comment: Thanks that was a big mistake. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Well, you know that $\operatorname{Arg} z_1 + \operatorname{Arg} z_2 = \operatorname{Arg}(z_1 z_2)$, so that takes care of that part of the angle.  We also know that $\log |z_1 z_2| = \log |z_1||z_2| = \log |z_1| + \log |z_2|$ from the corresponding identity for the positive reals, so that takes care of the magnitude.  All that remains is to show that the two sets $$\{k_1 + k_2 : k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb Z\}$$ and $$\{k_3 : k_3 \in \mathbb Z\}$$ are equivalent.

Comment: $Argz_1+Argz_2=Arg(z_1z_2)$ is not true however $arg(z_1)+arg(z_2)=arg(z_1z_2
$

Comment: I mean that is not true in general

Comment: Indeed, you are correct.  But can you see how to justify it?  We are talking about sets.

Comment: How to justify that $Argz_1+Argz_2=Arg(z_1z_2)$?

Answer (score 1):

It is true that

$$\log(z_1z_2)=\log(z_1)+\log(z_2) \tag1$$

***when*** $(1)$ is interpreted as a set equivalence.

This means that any value of $\log(z_1z_2)$ can be expressed as the sum of ***some*** value of $\log(z_1)$ and ***some*** value of $\log(z_2)$.  And conversely, it means that the sum of any value of $\log(z_1)$ and any value of $\log(z_2)$ can be expressed as some value of $\log(z_1z_2)$.

Note that $(1)$ is true since $\log(|z_1z_2|)=\log(|z_1|)+\log(|z_2|)$ and $\arg(z_1z_2)=\arg(z_1)+\arg(z_2)$.

To see that $\arg(z_1z_2)=\arg(z_1)+\arg(z_2)$, we write $z_1 = |z_1| e^{i\phi_1}$ and $z_2=|z_2|e^{i\phi_2}$.  Clearly, $z_1z_2=|z_1||z_2|e^{i(\phi_1+\phi_2)}$.  So any argument of $z_1$ plus any argument of $z_2$ is an argument of $z_1z_2$.  On the other hand consider any argument of $z_1z_2$, which is of the form $\phi_1+\phi_2+2n\pi$ for some integer $n$.  We could simply take $\arg(z_1)=\phi_1$ and $\arg(z_2)=\phi_2+2n\pi$ and have the stated equality hold.

---

> **NOTE:** It is important to understand that $(1)$ does not hold in general if $\log(z)$ is taken on the Principal branch of the complex logarithm (or any other designated branch since then we lose a degree of freedom).

---

As an example, take $z_1=i$ and $z_2=-i$.  Then, if we choose $\log(i)=i\pi/2$ and $\log(-i)=-i\pi/2$, then we must choose the branch of $\log(z)$ for which $\log(1)=0$.  If on the other hand we choose $\log(i)=-i3\pi/2$ and $\log(-i)=-i\pi/2$, then we must choose the branch of $\log(z)$ for which $\log(1)=-i2\pi$.

Conversely, if we choose the branch of $\log(z)$ for which $\log(1)=0$, then for $\log(i)=-i3\pi/2$, we must have $\log(-i)=-i\pi/2$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.